# Relationship between the expected value of the determinant and the determinant of the expected value?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, probability-theory, determinant, random-matrices

Let $X$ be an $n \times n$ matrix of random variables. Is $E[\det(X)] = \det(E[X])$?

If it doesn't hold in general, under what assumptions on $X$ does it hold?

Comment: If all the entries of X are independent then the identity holds since the determinant is just sums and multiplications of X’s entries

Comment: What about if the random variables in each row are not independent of one another, but each row vector is independent of the other row vectors?

Comment: Since $\frac12(\det A + \det B)$ is rarely equal to $\det\left(\frac{A+B}2\right)$, you know that it cannot hold in much generality at all.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true in general. Let $X= [A, B ; C , D] \in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$. Then the statement is equivalent with $E[ AD - BC ] = E[A]E[D]- E[B]E[C]$. If $B$ and $C$ are uncorrelated, but $A$ and $D$ are correlated, this is false. @yotam maoz is right though that it does hold in the case when the entries are independent. As suggested by @Lorenzo Najt, if only rather the rows or columns are independent, then the same holds, since when calculating the determinant, one can expand along the rows or the columns, calculating the determinant by multiplying each entry in a row/column by the determinant of the corresponding minorant matrix, which will be comprised of sums/products of uncorrelated terms.

Comment: I think if the columns (or rows) are stochastically independent random vectors, then each term in the determinant is a product of independent random variables. So I'm confused about what you are saying about the last comment.

Comment: I think you are correct! I miss interpreted that comment. I've edited the answer.